# DebugPrint pushes empty line (Serial connection)

Tags: c, edk2

Upon deciding to write a simple "Hello World!" program in EDK2,
I stumbled upon the following problem:

As I am using a serial connection for debugging, the output of the debug functions like **DebugPrint** successfully get redirected to my serial terminal (PuTTY in this case), *well sort of.*

After compiling an executing the following program inside an UEFI shell, I simply get
an empty line as a result.
But after executing the same binary again, the line gets successfully printed in all it's beauty.

This is the source code of the program i ran:

```
#include <Uefi.h>
#include <Library/DebugLib.h>

EFI_STATUS
efi_main(EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, 
    EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE* SystemTable
    )
{
    DebugPrint(DEBUG_INFO, "Hello World!\n");
    return EFI_SUCCESS;
}
```

Serial output:

[image]

Note: I linked my program against **IoLib**, **SerialPortLib** and **DebugLib**

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Try `DebugPrint(DEBUG_INFO, "Hello World!\n"); DebugPrint(DEBUG_INFO, "Hello World!\n");` and `DebugPrint(DEBUG_INFO, "Hello World!\nHello World!\n");` and see what happens

Comment: Already tried that one out, but that sadly didn't help either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling around I realised, that I manually specified the entry point to my main-function (`efi_main`), which should instead point to `_ModuleEntryPoint` when using the **UefiDriverEntryPoint** library from EDK2.

This solved my problem instantly :)